# Random Forest Feature Importance Chart using Python

Tags: python, plot, random-forest, feature-selection

I am working with RandomForestRegressor in python and I want to create a chart that will illustrate the ranking of feature importance. This is the code I used:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

MT= pd.read_csv("MT_reduced.csv") 
df = MT.reset_index(drop = False)

columns2 = df.columns.tolist()

# Filter the columns to remove ones we don't want.
columns2 = [c for c in columns2 if c not in["Violent_crime_rate","Change_Property_crime_rate","State","Year"]]

# Store the variable we'll be predicting on.
target = "Property_crime_rate"

# Let’s randomly split our data with 80% as the train set and 20% as the test set:

# Generate the training set.  Set random_state to be able to replicate results.
train2 = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)

#exclude all obs with matching index
test2 = df.loc[~df.index.isin(train2.index)]

print(train2.shape) #need to have same number of features only difference should be obs
print(test2.shape)

# Initialize the model with some parameters.

model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=8, random_state=1)

#n_estimators= number of trees in forrest
#min_samples_leaf= min number of samples at each leaf


# Fit the model to the data.
model.fit(train2[columns2], train2[target])
# Make predictions.
predictions_rf = model.predict(test2[columns2])
# Compute the error.
mean_squared_error(predictions_rf, test2[target])#650.4928
```

## Feature Importance

```
features=df.columns[[3,4,6,8,9,10]]
importances = model.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Feature Importances')
plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='b', align='center')
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices])
plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
```

This feature importance code was altered from an example found on http://www.agcross.com/2015/02/random-forests-in-python-with-scikit-learn/

I receive the following error when I attempt to replicate the code with my data:

```
  IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6
```

Also, only one feature shows up on my chart with 100% importance where there are no labels.

Any help solving this issue so I can create this chart will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here is an example using the iris data set.

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>>> iris = load_iris()
>>> rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500, n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)
>>> rnd_clf.fit(iris["data"], iris["target"])
>>> for name, importance in zip(iris["feature_names"], rnd_clf.feature_importances_):
...     print(name, "=", importance)

sepal length (cm) = 0.112492250999
sepal width (cm) = 0.0231192882825
petal length (cm) = 0.441030464364
petal width (cm) = 0.423357996355
```

Plotting feature importance

```
>>> features = iris['feature_names']
>>> importances = rnd_clf.feature_importances_
>>> indices = np.argsort(importances)

>>> plt.title('Feature Importances')
>>> plt.barh(range(len(indices)), importances[indices], color='b', align='center')
>>> plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), [features[i] for i in indices])
>>> plt.xlabel('Relative Importance')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: Feature importances]

Comment: it seems that the y label is wrong, you know the max score is petal length, but the figure shows is petal width

Comment: to fix the y-labels I changed `plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features['indices'])`

Answer (score 66):

Load the feature importances into a pandas series indexed by your column names, then use its plot method. e.g. for an sklearn RF classifier/regressor `model` trained using `df`:

```
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=df.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(4).plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make the colors? On my plot all bars are blue.

Comment: This is the default for my version of matplotlib, but you could easily recreate something like this passing the arg `colors=['blue', 'orange', 'green, 'red']` to .plot(), or use and of the named colors here: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/color/named_colors.html

Comment: To invert the `y axis`: `feat_importances = pd.Series(rfr.feature_importances_, index=X_train.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh').invert_yaxis()`

Comment: `df.columns` will take even the target variable right? how arent  you getting an error

Comment: @Scope, use your X_train then, instead of df

Answer (score 10):

The method you are trying to apply is using built-in feature importance of Random Forest. This method can sometimes prefer numerical features over categorical and can prefer high cardinality categorical features. Please see this [article](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/) for details. There are two other methods to get feature importance (but also with their pros and cons).

## Permutation based Feature Importance

In `scikit-learn` from version `0.22` there is method: [`permutation_importance`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html). It is model agnostic. It can even work with algorithms from other packages if they follow the `scikit-learn` interface. The complete code example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
import shap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# prepare the data
boston = load_boston()
X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = boston.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=12)

# train the model
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# the permutation based importance
perm_importance = permutation_importance(rf, X_test, y_test)

sorted_idx = perm_importance.importances_mean.argsort()
plt.barh(boston.feature_names[sorted_idx], perm_importance.importances_mean[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance")
```

[image: Random Forest variable importance based on permutation]

The permutation-based importance can be computationally expensive and can omit highly correlated features as important.

## SHAP based importance

Feature Importance can be computed with Shapley values (you need [`shap`](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) package).

```py
import shap
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

[image: Random Forest Feature Importance SHAP]

Once SHAP values are computed, other plots can be done:

[image: SHAP summary plot for Random Forest]

Computing SHAP values can be computationally expensive. The full example of 3 methods to compute Random Forest feature importance can be found in this [blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/) of mine.

Comment: The shapely value you brought is a good deal. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 6):

A **barplot** would be **more than useful** in order to **visualize** the **importance** of the **features**.

**Use this (example using Iris Dataset):**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Create decision tree classifer object
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
# Train model
model = clf.fit(X, y)

# Calculate feature importances
importances = model.feature_importances_
# Sort feature importances in descending order
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

# Rearrange feature names so they match the sorted feature importances
names = [iris.feature_names[i] for i in indices]

# Barplot: Add bars
plt.bar(range(X.shape[1]), importances[indices])
# Add feature names as x-axis labels
plt.xticks(range(X.shape[1]), names, rotation=20, fontsize = 8)
# Create plot title
plt.title("Feature Importance")
# Show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The y-ticks are not correct. To fix it, it should be

```
plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), [features[i] for i in indices])
```

Answer (score 1):

This code from spies006 dont work : `plt.yticks(range(len(indices)), features[indices])` so you have to change it for `plt.yticks(range(len(indices)),features.columns[indices])`

Answer (score 0):

In the above code from spies006, "feature_names" didn't work for me. A generic solution would be to use name_of_the_dataframe.columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Create decision tree classifer object
clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
# Train model
model = clf.fit(X, y)

feat_importances = pd.DataFrame(model.feature_importances_, index=iris.feature_names, columns=["Importance"])
feat_importances.sort_values(by='Importance', ascending=False, inplace=True)
feat_importances.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(8,6))
```

[image]

```
print(feat_importances)
```

and we get:

```
                   Importance
petal width (cm)     0.489820
petal length (cm)    0.368047
sepal length (cm)    0.118965
sepal width (cm)     0.023167
```